# Mailparse en xampp php 7.2

Tags: php, xampp

Estoy tratando de instalar dicha extensión (mailparse) , hice lo mismo pasos para instalar otras extensiones , la descargue y luego la agregue en el php/ext y luego lo agregue en mi php.ini  `extension=mailparse` , reinicie el apache y me muestra..

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mailparse' (tried:

```
D:\xampp\php\ext\mailparse (No se puede encontrar el mdulo especificado. 

), D:\xampp\php\ext\php_mailparse.dll (No se puede encontrar el mdulo especificado. 

)) in Unknown on line 0 



Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mailparse' (tried: D:\xampp\php\ext\mailparse (No se puede encontrar el mdulo especificado. 

), D:\xampp\php\ext\php_mailparse.dll (No se puede encontrar el mdulo especificado. 

)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Descargue la extensión de https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mailparse/3.0.2/php_mailparse-3.0.2-7.2-nts-vc15-x86.zip

También probé con https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mailparse/3.0.2/php_mailparse-3.0.2-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que nesecites otra extensión:

> Mailparse requiere la extensión [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mbstring.php), y mbstring debe
>   cargarse antes mailparse.

Puedes verlo en http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mailparse.php